# XML to WPF nested listview binding and multiple select items

Tags: xml, wpf, product

I'm new to WPF and have this assignment to do:
I have the attached xml file obviously with two levels.
How can I create parent listview displaying the first level **PRODUCT** Items with its attributes and under each **PRODUCT** item I should display the child level **PRODUCTID** items in another listview.
Moreover I have to make the items of the PRODUCT multi-selectable.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<Products>
<Product Name="Red" File="FileRed" ColorLock="0">
    <ProductID ProductNumber="p01" FlowRate="8" Finish="" CAD="540" USD="520" EU="410"/>
    <ProductID ProductNumber="p02" FlowRate="5" Finish="" CAD="540" USD="520" EU="410"/>
</Product>
<Product Name="Green" File="FileGreen" ColorLock="0">
    <ProductID ProductNumber="4000" FlowRate="4" Finish="PowderCoat" CAD="540" USD="520" EU="410"/>
    <ProductID ProductNumber="4009" FlowRate="4" Finish="Polished" CAD="540" USD="520" EU="410"/>       
    <ProductID ProductNumber="4100" FlowRate="2.5" Finish="PowderCoat" CAD="540" USD="520" EU="410"/>       
    <ProductID ProductNumber="4109" FlowRate="2.5" Finish="Polished" CAD="540" USD="520" EU="410"/>     
</Product>
<Product Name="Blue" File="FileBlue" ColorLock="0">
    <ProductID ProductNumber="2000" FlowRate="15" Finish="PowderCoat" CAD="3370" USD="3210" EU="2530"/>
</Product>
```

Comment: Please submit the sample XML file, to make easier to receive a answer.

Comment: You can refer [Databinding for nested collections in XAML (WPF and Silverlight) - WebX - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harryh/archive/2010/06/12/nested-collections-databinding-in-xaml-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ListView has a property called [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) which let's you decide the template in which you want to use to display the ListView's items. You can create another ListView to display the inner level products set it as ItemTemplate of the main ListView

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- Displays first level attributes -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding File}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorLock}"/>

                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductIDs}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <!-- Displays the second level attributes -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductNumber}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FlowRate}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Finish}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CAD}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding USD}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding EU}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Assuming that the nodes in your XML is represented by *Models* classes of `Product` and `ProductID` each containing a property per attribute, and a *ViewModel* class that contains a collection of `Product` classes set as this xaml's `DataContext`.